# unicode-math and order of setmath commands

Tags: unicode-math

Consider the following MWE

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\setmathfont{Lucida Bright Math OT}[StylisticSet=4]
\setmathfont{XITS Math}[range=\boxdiag]

\begin{document}
$\mathcal{ABCDEFO}$
\end{document}
```

The expected output is

[image]

but actually I get this output

[image]

If I swap the lines

```
\setmathfont{Lucida Bright Math OT}[StylisticSet=4]
\setmathfont{XITS Math}[range=\boxdiag]
```

then I get the expected output. I thought that if I use the range option, then the effect of setting a math font is only limited to such symbols in the specific range. But it seems to me that this is not the case. Why do I have to load XITS Math before Lucida Math, if I want the stylistic set 4?

**Edit:**
It gets even worse ;-) I cannot manage to get the stylistic set number 4 of the Lucida fond and get the single symbol `\boxdiag` from XITS. The following code

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\setmathfont{XITS Math}[range=\boxdiag]
\setmathfont{Lucida Bright Math OT}[StylisticSet=4]

\begin{document}
$\mathcal{ABCDEFO}\boxdiag\mathcal{G}$
\end{document}
```

produces this output where `\boxdiag` is empty, but the stylistic set number 4 is used for the Lucida font:

[image]

and if the `setmathfont` lines are swapped as follows

```
\setmathfont{Lucida Bright Math OT}[StylisticSet=4]
\setmathfont{XITS Math}[range=\boxdiag]
```

then I get this output where `\boxdiag` is not empty, but the stylistic set number 4 is not used for the Lucida font:

[image]

That means, I do not get both working at the same time.

Comment: The range option is buggy. You can find some issues on the github site.